# Java Bitwise & Operator Matching Multiple Conditions

Tags: java

I'm attempting to use java's Bitwise *&* operator and I think I'm misusing it.  Using the below example, with messageAddress of 7 both condition 1 and condition 3 are satisfied.  Shouldn't a messageAddress of 7 just meet the 3rd condition and not the first?  Any ideas on how to change the below logic so that messageAddress of 7 would only meet the last condition?

```
    public static final int SLOW = 1;
    public static final int SMEDIUM = 2;
    public static final int SHIGH = 3;
        String messageAddressHex="7";
        int messageAddress = Integer.parseInt(messageAddressHex, 16);
        if ((messageAddress & SLOW) == SLOW) {
                   //condition 1 met logic
                } else if ((messageAddress & SMEDIUM) == SMEDIUM) {
                    //condition 2 met logic
                } else if ((messageAddress & SHIGH) == SHIGH) {
                    //condition 3 met logic
                }
```

Comment: I suggest using binary numbers instead of decimal numbers, that way it's easier to see how your bitwise operations are going to work. And just use powers of 2, that will simplify things.

Comment: (I find hexadecimal literals better; easier to deal with than decimal as they align with bits well and they are supported as literals in Java. Otherwise, one has to `parseInt(binary,2)` or similar .. bit shifting is also handy, though: `1 << 3`, e.g.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, `condition 1` is all the odd numbers, `condition 2` is all the numbers with their second least significant bit turned on, and `condition 3` is a combination of 1 and 2.

I assume that what you really want is to check the two least significant bits as a number between 0 and 3. If that's the case, you should use:

```
if ((messageAddress & SHIGH) == SLOW) {
    //condition 1 met logic
} else if ((messageAddress & SHIGH) == SMEDIUM) {
    //condition 2 met logic
} else if ((messageAddress & SHIGH) == SHIGH) {
    //condition 3 met logic
}
```

**EDIT:**
It's a much better design to declare another constant as the bit mask:

```
public static final int MASK=3;
```

And then we can write:

```
if ((messageAddress & MASK) == SLOW) {
    //condition 1 met logic
} else if ((messageAddress & MASK) == SMEDIUM) {
    //condition 2 met logic
} else if ((messageAddress & MASK) == SHIGH) {
    //condition 3 met logic
}
```

The number 3 has two roles - `MASK`, which is used as the bitmask to filter only the two last bits, and `SHIGH` - which is one of the possible values for the last two bits that you want to check.

BTW, now you can use a `switch-case` statement instead of the `if-else-if` chain:

```
switch (messageAddress & MASK) {
    case SLOW:
        //condition 1 met logic
        break;
    case SMEDIUM:
        //condition 2 met logic
        break;
    case SHIGH:
        //condition 3 met logic
        break;
}
```

Comment: what is the significance of using the SHIGH value in the bitwise comparison? I don't quite understand why that works

Comment: Well, it might be better to define another constant to be 3, and use it as the bit mask for all the comparison(I'll update it in the answer). Anyways, a bitwise and returns all the bits that are turned on in both operands. The number 3 is 00000011 in binary, so doing a bitwise and with 3 will return the last two bits. After doing that, the condition checks if the last two bits are 01, 10 or 11. If you perform the bitwise and with `SLOW` or `SMEDIUM`, you only check the lowest bit or the second lowest bit. Therefore, if the last two bits are turned on, condition 1 and 2 will both yield true.

Answer (score 4):

For bitwise masks to be effective, you need to use powers of two.

`3 = 1 | 2`, thus for any `x & 3 != 0`, `x & 1 != 0` and `x & 2 != 0`.

To explain in a bit more detail, 7 is `1 + 2 + 4` or, in binary, `111`.  Note that the 1 bit is high (and thus 7 & 1 == 1).

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation of `7` is `111` (notice, all ones). Therefore, `7 & ANYTHING == ANYTHING` will always return `true` for anything less than or equal to `7` and greater than or equal to `0`. For example, `7 & 3`:

> 111 & 011
>
> First bit:  0 (1 & 0)
>   Second bit: 1 (1 & 1)
>   Third bit:  1 (1 & 1)

Notice how you just receive the second argument again.

Answer (score 1):

```
  111 (=7)
& 001 (=1)
----------
  001 (=1)
```

You can check binary representation of int value by `Integer.toBinaryString` method.